# Eslint fails to parse and red-highlights optional chaining (?.) and nullish coalescing (??) operators

Tags: javascript, babeljs, eslint

I am looking for the relevant eslint rules for

- @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining
- @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator

My editor highlights in red when I do the following

```js
const baz = obj?.foo?.bar?.baz; // 42
const safe = obj?.qux?.baz; // undefined
const foo = obj.baz ?? 'default'; // default
// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
console.log('baz', baz);
// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
console.log('safe', safe);
// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
console.log('foo', foo);
```

The code works properly, but eslint highlights my code in red.

Reference:

- https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining
- https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator

Answer (score 61):

Nullish coalescing operator is natively supported starting from `eslint>=7.5.0`.

The easiest is set ES2020 in your package.json:

```
{
  "eslintConfig":
  {
    "parserOptions":
    {
      "ecmaVersion": 2020
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You probably mean `ecmaVersion`, not `exmaVersion`?

Comment: Looks like canonical is `ecmaVersion: 11` or `12`, while `2020` and `2021` are de facto accepted as aliases: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options

Comment: For me I found "parserOptions" in `.eslintrc.json` and resolved this problem

Answer (score 8):

add the following config to your `eslint`:

```
"parser": "babel-eslint"
```

Comment: More Context: 

Create .eslintrc.json
Add {"parser": "babel-eslint"}
Save

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the parser on your eslint config to "babel-eslint"? https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-eslint It's the recommended parser when using experimental features not supported in eslint yet.

Comment: This throws up tons of typescript errors when i change from `@typescript-eslint/parser`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this plugin: https://github.com/babel/eslint-plugin-babel

You can then disable the original eslint-rule and enable the babel version of it, which will then show no false errors. Your eslint-config could then look like this:

```
{
  parser: "babel-eslint",
  rules: {
    "no-unused-expressions": 0,
    "babel/no-unused-expressions": 1
  },
  plugins: ["babel"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
parserOptions: {
  ecmaVersion: "latest",
},
```

to .eslintrc.js did the trick for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @Katlego, I had to lower the rating of this answer because writing `ecmaVersion: "latest"` doesn't solve the issue but creates a bigger one. The trailing comma after the word `"latest"` crashes the ESLint configuration as it's JSON, not JS. The parsing of the .eslintrc.json file is broken, and as a result, ESLint just stopped working. That's why the red squiggly line disappeared.

Comment: I would just like to add that  this answer worked for me. And as @Katelgo specifically mentioned, they are using .eslintrc*.js*, which is Javascript, so trailing commas and lack of quotes are fine.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021 after `babel-eslint` became decprecated, you can fix this issue by upgrading to `@babel/eslint-parser`.

The configuration needed to be added to .eslintrc.json is:

```json
"parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
"parserOptions": {
    "requireConfigFile": false,
    "presets": [
         "@babel/preset-env"
     ]
}
```

`"requireConfigFile": false,` - you need this line if you don't have a dedicated eslint config file

Also, make sure to upgrade to eslint versin 7 and above, and remove `babel-eslint` as it's been replaced by `@babel/eslint-parser`.

Setting the babel parser's options, like `"plugins": [ "jsx" ]` or `"plugins": [ "typescript" ]` are required only if you do use react or typescript.

```json
"babelOptions": {
      "parserOpts": {
          "plugins": [ "jsx", "typescript" ]
      }
  }
```

So if you also need React, your final config changes could look like this:

```json
"parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
"parserOptions": {
    "requireConfigFile": false,
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "babelOptions": {
        "parserOpts": {
            "plugins": [ "jsx" ]
        }
    }
},
"plugins": [
    "react",
    "react-hooks"
]
```