# JSHint suppress error for optional chaining

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jshint, optional-chaining

I was writing some Javascript when I found out about [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`). I decided that I would need it in some code I was writing. When I finished typing out the code, I noticed that JSHint was giving me an error that stated `Expected an identifier and instead saw '.'. (E030) jshint(E030)`. The following code runs without any error ([MDN compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#Browser_compatibility)), but JSHint still gives a warning for it.

```js
var x = {
  y: {
    z: 123
  }
};

console.log(x.y?.z)
```

I have found another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57378411/eslint-rule-for-optional-chaining-nullish-coalescing-operator) relating to this, but the question specifically asks about ESLint, while this question is about JSHint. I also searched the issues tab of the JSHint GitHub repository, but I couldn't find anything. Is there any way to suppress this kind of error? I am using Visual Studio Code Insiders.

The editor information taken from `Code - Insiders > About Visual Studio Code - Insiders`:

```
Version: 1.48.0-insider
Commit: d13d2fc56da7a2f8bcad4256212db0661fcbba45
Date: 2020-08-05T05:26:44.946Z (20 hrs ago)
Electron: 7.3.2
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.5.0
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a warning, more like a plain syntax error where jshint cannot parse this recently added syntax.

Comment: @Bergi Okay, I will edit the question and change "warning" to "error"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add: `"esversion": 11` to your jshint file. Optional chaining was added in version 11.

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue open for this in https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/3448.

It suggests "You can use the `ignore:start`/`ignore:end` or `ignore:line` directives to cause JSHint to pass over any syntax it doesn't recognize."

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seems to work when upgraded by yarn

```
node -v
v16.2.0
```

.jshint in project folder

```
cat .jshintrc 
{
    "-W138": true,
    "-W083": true,
    "esversion": 11
}
```

from package.json:

```
"grunt-contrib-jshint": "^3.0.0",
"jshint": "^2.13.1",
```

from gruntfile.js

```
jshint: {
    options: {
        "-W138": true,
        "-W083": true,
        "jshintrc": true,
        esversion: 11
    },
    files: ['src/js/**/*.js']
},
```

result:

```
grunt jshint:files
if (response?.errCode != 200) {
             ^ Expected an identifier and instead saw '.'.
```

some investignation:

```
node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/node_modules/jshint/package.json
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/jshint/jshint.git"
},
```

in repository is proper (2.13.1) version of jshint but in my project it isn't updated (still have 2.12.0)

solution #1:

```
throw new Exception(response?.errMessage); /* jshint ignore:line */
```

solution #2:

```
cd node_modules
cp -Rp jshint grunt-contrib-jshint/node_modules/
```